# Openpyxl: listing all defined names of a workbook

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to read in all the data contained in named ranges in a xlsx workbook across multiple sheets, but for the purposes of this exercise, I don't know what the names of any named ranges will be ahead of time.

I can access `wb.defined_names` but this returns a DefinedNameList; if I try to iterate over it I don't seem to be able to access any of the data underneath.

**How can I access the names of named ranges and the corresponding cell references as a list of strings?**

Context: Up until now I have been achieving this with xlwings, but am having issues with xlwings opening a wb whilst I have other wb tabs open. Switching to openpyxl seems like a good possible solution if I can fix this issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[dn for dn in wb.defined_names.definedName]
```

Comment: How can I also get the corresponding cell references for each name? e.g. $A$2:$D$5

Comment: The `definedName` objects contain all the relevant information.  Maybe you should make your question clearer.

Comment: I see now, the list comp gives me the `definedName` object and I can access its attributes through `dn.attr_text` etc. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the comprehension itself isn't necessary but you can use it for searching or extraction. You need to look at the source for this kind of thing.

Comment: This only seems to work for named ranges; do you know how to include named tables in the result?

Comment: Named ranges are workbook globals. For Tables you'd have to loop over all the worksheets and create your own list: openpyxl currently provides no API for managing them.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple command for Openpyxl version>3.1.0.

```
excel_file_path = r"sheet.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(excel_file_path)
Name_Ranges = list(wb.defined_names)# all name ranges in this list
print(Name_Ranges)
```